# How to do simple hash mark (hash tag) routing in AngularJs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am looking for the simplest solution to use hash mark identifiers in AngularJS.
I am using AngularJS version 1.2.22

My code as follows:

App.config

```
// in app config:
$routeProvider.when("/:page_id", {template: '', controller: "PageController"});
```

Controller

```
// in PageController - where I would like to read the most recent #value
$scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(event) {
    // What do I grab here?

    /* I have tried the followings
    - $routeParams.page_id -> keeps previous value (documentation says too it will)
    - $route.current.params.page_id (current is undefined when trying to access)
    */    
});
```

URL changing code

```
// my trigger code is a simple $location.path()
$location.path('/'+page_id);
$(
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use the resolve property ([plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/sOG224TQyXMXrbVwkxMa?p=preview)):

```
$routeProvider.when('/:page_id', {
  template: '<pre>{{page| json}}</pre>',
  controller: 'PageController',
  resolve: {
    page: function($route,  $q) {
      var id = $route.current.params.page_id;

      var promise = $q.when({ id: id }); // fetch the page data from the server
      return promise;
    }
  }
});
```

Then it is injected into your contoller:

```
app.controller('PageController', function($scope, page) {
  $scope.page = page;


});
```